# SQL Server Installaion error 0x84B40000

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a problem installing SQL Server 2008 R2. Long time ago I had it installed, and then uninstalled. It was left in "Add/remove programs", but I didn't pay attention on that. I had 2005 installed. And now there is a need to install 2008. I removed 2005 and started installing 2008, but it says that space on C: is not enough. That's when I found out that "Add/remove programs" shows it occupying more than 4 gigabytes, though I used to uninstall it. So I click "Remove", it shows all those many screens and validations, shows that removal completed, but the size of Program Files folder is still more than 4 GB. I removed (from "Add\remove programs" everything that had "SQL Server" in it's name, but that main "SQL Server 2008" item is still there and still 4 GB and uninstalling does nothing.
Because installation of SQL Server did not show existing instances, and I don't see any running services related to SQL server (well, almost any, more details in the end), I though that this folder contains just some leftover staff and data and deleted it manually. Then agreed to removing of the item in "Add/remove programs" and everything looks clean.
Now every time I try to install SQL Server (even in the minimum configuration), I receive the following error:

```
    SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:

    The specified credentials that were provided for the SQL Server service are not
valid. To continue, provide a valid account and password for the SQL Server service.

    Error code 0x84B40000.
```

What is this service mentioned here? This error looks like I'm trying to add features to existing server and it can't login. But the setup didn't ask me for any credentials, except one username that couldn't be changed.
Here are the services shown that can be related, both disabled and pointing to non-existing executables:

1. SQL Active Directory Helper Service
2. SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (MSSQLSERVER)

I understand that this must be because of my manual deletion, but is there a way to clean it up now?

Comment: Not a programming question. Vote to move to superuser.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the credentials used for the service account?

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\MSSQLFDLauncher` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\MSSQLServerADHelper100` present? The ObjectName key is what has the credentials used to run the service.

I would say backup and delete the two keys above as well as `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\MSSQLSERVER`